# Java Websocket client using Tyrus javax.websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket, tyrus

I need to connect to already made WebSocket server (ws://173.230.152.100:2828/) using Java and exchange data. It must be possible to use multiple websockets at the same time, so it shouldn't be static class.

I found some examples, but I always get errors and etc..

I need some simple example that works, and maybe a library download link that is used.

How to connect to multiple WebSocket servers using Tyrus library, or other library?

Comment: Please be aware of increasing chances to give you correct and precise answer – share code you tried and errors. StackOverflow  is not code writing service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found easy to use library:

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket